# Get file url from sharepoint by name

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

I'm able to save document in Sharepoint documents. Once the document is saved I want to be able to get the url of that document so I can share the url with a user.

This is the code I'm using to save the document:

```cs
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://mydomain.sharepoint.com"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "mypassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myaccount@mydomain.com", passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    //newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    byte[] docData = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        docData = ms.ToArray();
    }
    newFile.Content = docData;
    newFile.Url = originalFileName;

    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("DOCUMENTS");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

How I can get the URL of that document once it's uploaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of the below 3 methods. To share a document, you can generate anonymous link, anon link with expiration date or share and send it via email.

```
List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("DOCUMENTS");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields, item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"]);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var fileUrl = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();

string link = clientContext.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument(fileUrl, ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);

string linkwithExpiration = clientContext.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkWithExpirationForDocument(fileUrl, ExternalSharingDocumentOption.Edit, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));

SharingResult result = clientContext.Web.ShareDocument(fileUrl, "someone@example.com", ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View, true, "Doc shared programmatically");
```

Ensure that external sharing capability is turned on.

Reference - [Turn on external sharing in SPO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-SharePoint-Online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, do you know I'm getting these errors http://prntscr.com/hauui3

Comment: looks like you are using on old version of CSOM. Download the latest ones from nuget or from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42038) and reference it in your project. The assembly version needs to be `16.x.x.x`

Comment: Also, check this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/04/10/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365/) on how to do it step by step.

Comment: Thanks, give me few minutes pls

Comment: I have the current version 16.1.0.0 but still the same @Gautam thx for your help. After installing that version from the link I actually got more errors now such as not recognizing this method GetAuthenticationCookie http://prntscr.com/hav5xv

Comment: add this line `clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;` after `clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials` and check.

Comment: Thanks but .AuthenticationMode is not recognized either. http://prntscr.com/havbct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159084/discussion-between-laziale-and-gautam-sheth).

Comment: Works great now, I was missing this package SharePointPnPCoreOnline

Answer (score 0):

To get url of uploaded file you could utilize the following properties:

- `EncodedAbsUrl` - gets the absolute url of file
- `EncodedAbsUrl` - gets the server relative url of file

They need to requested explicitly once the file is getting uploaded like this:

```
var uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
ctx.Load(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields,item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"], item => item["FileRef"]);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Example

```
var fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
fileInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
fileInfo.Url = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
ctx.Load(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields,item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"], item => item["FileRef"]);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Console.WriteLine(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["EncodedAbsUrl"]);
Console.WriteLine(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["FileRef"]);
```

**Update**

To get the url of display form of document you could

```
ctx.Load(list, l => l.DefaultDisplayFormUrl);
ctx.Load(uploadFile.ListItemAllFields,item => item.Id);
ctx.Load(ctx.Site, s => s.Url);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

var itemUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}?ID={2}",ctx.Site.Url,list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl, uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. How about getting the Url for public access? Thanks again

Comment: @Laziale, i might misunderstood your question but if by public access you mean shared link of a file, there is a specific class available for that matter [ObjectSharingInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.objectsharinginformation.aspx) but it is not supported in SharePoint **2010** version

Comment: Thanks Vadim, how about shareable link if the sharepoint version is 2013, we are using the sharepoint online version